# Show all points in Chart - NVD3

Tags: nvd3.js

I am using NVD3.js and I am trying to show all points in a chart by default. Without doing onhover, I want to view all points in chart, Please advise how can I achieve this.

thanks,
Balaji

Comment: What NVD3 chart are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am using all the chart types of NVd3

Comment: Yes, but in a bar chart all the point are visible, so could you be a bit more specific with your question! Line Chart, cumulative Line Chart or Stacked Area Chart ?

Comment: please help me with line chart

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is an NVD3 Line Plot with Markers Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732971/is-an-nvd3-line-plot-with-markers-possible)

Comment: this also might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883686/fix-label-with-rcharts-in-a-shiny-application   see the last function added to run on the draw callback.

Comment: I tried doing show all points based on previous answer, but results like this, where all my points are getting scattered.. please find the fiddle link below,   http://jsfiddle.net/balajipalamadai/d2Dj6/4/

Answer (score 1):

Add custom attribute and class to your nvd3 tag and write some custom css for particular chart .

```
<style>
    .line-chart[data-points="true"] .nvd3.nv-line .nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point {
        stroke-width: 6px;
        fill-opacity: 1;
        stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    }
</style>
```

`
[View In Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/Pd7T2Eh5HVPrlSSiQN5s/)

Answer (score 0):

In some of them you can do something like **showValues**

```
nv.addGraph(function() {  
  var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .staggerLabels(true)
      //.staggerLabels(historicalBarChart[0].values.length > 8)
      .tooltips(false)
      .showValues(true)
```

I saw you have put for "line chart" and I tried without success. Honestly, I have been trying with the default example, so I thought that maybe it makes no sense to show all the values because they are curves. What I mean is, it can be possible that for some reason when is rendering showvalues or similar is gonna try to show all the values in the curve and it won't work. Anyway, I am starting with nvd3 as well, but hope this help to figure it out how it can be done.