# How can I plot a zoomable plot in knitr

Tags: r, plot, knitr, interactive

I an using `knitr` for automatic html reports. I would like to be able to plot simple scatter plots (like time serie plots) but interactive ones, that would be zoomable.
Ideally I could then use it in a `knitr` html document.
I had a look at `rgl` but it seems overkill for my simple needs. What should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into `ggvis` and/or `rCharts`.
Especcaly have a look at this example page of stock-data with `rCharts`:
http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_time_series/history.html
"rCharts 2013" might be interessting for you.

And this is an example of Markdown with knitr and rCharts:
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/9331_9b5778029d1e46d0b3afcf1d861d7e70.html

Comment: thanks for adding the links.  In this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883686/fix-label-with-rcharts-in-a-shiny-application/24898563#24898563 a similar request was made for a zoomable scatter.  Since that makes 2 votes, I am more motivated to make one.  I'll let you know.