# Plots in R Shiny including Javascript (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, shiny, nvd3.js

I am familiar with R, but completely new to java-script. Please pardon me if my question is elementary. I wanted to incorporate some javascript elements into my Shiny application.

I want to display a donut plot based on user input. (for instance, like the following: http://codepen.io/MeredithU/pen/LVVoNE)

The donut plot should be based on user input, and I am looking to nvD3 and d3.js to create the plot.

1. How do I send slider inputs to the javascript file for creating the plot?
2. The current attempt to include the js file in the script does not output on the screen. The js, css, and html files are in a separate www folder. (The js, css, html files are the same as the ones in the codepen link)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "Simple Risk Calc",
    titleWidth = 335
  ),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("MENU ITEM")
    )
  ),
  body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(title = tags$b("Demographic Information"), status = "success", width = 20, 
          collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = FALSE,
          valueBox("Age", subtitle = tags$b(h4("15")), icon = icon("user"), width = 3),
          valueBox("Gender", subtitle = tags$b("Male"), icon = icon("users"), width = 3),
          valueBox("Location", subtitle = tags$b("Urban"), icon = icon("ambulance"), width = 3),

        )
    ),

    fluidRow(
      tags$head(tags$script(src="index.js")),

    )
  ),

  dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
)
```

SERVER.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})
```

Comment: I don't know much about shiny, but [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/custom-input-bindings.html) might help with that part. Otherwise, you can try d3 selections, or try `document.getElementByID(ID-of-your-input-element-goes-here).value`

Comment: Take a look at [rcharts](http://rcharts.io/) and shiny, you can do it without having to import any javascript code

Comment: I took a look at the nvD3 library in rCharts. (http://ramnathv.github.io/posts/rcharts-nvd3/index.html). Only issue is that I want to make modifications to the donut plot. For instance, I want to add a number to the middle of plot. Any suggestions NicE?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883686/fix-label-with-rcharts-in-a-shiny-application), you can add a callback function to the template used by `rCharts` to modify the plot.

Here is an example with shiny and the part of your code that adds the text in the middle of the donut plot:

```
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderChart2({
    mtcars2 <- subset(mtcars, cyl < input$obs1)
    p5<-nPlot(~ cyl, data = mtcars2, type = 'pieChart')
    p5$chart(donut = TRUE)

    #original template is from
    #https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/nvd3/layouts/chart.html
    p5$setTemplate(script = sprintf('
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                    draw{{chartId}}()
                                    });
                                    function draw{{chartId}}(){  
                                    var opts = {{{ opts }}},
                                    data = {{{ data }}}

                                    if(!(opts.type==="pieChart" || opts.type==="sparklinePlus" || opts.type==="bulletChart")) {
                                    var data = d3.nest()
                                    .key(function(d){
                                    //return opts.group === undefined ? main : d[opts.group]
                                    //instead of main would think a better default is opts.x
                                    return opts.group === undefined ? opts.y : d[opts.group];
                                    })
                                    .entries(data);
                                    }

                                    if (opts.disabled != undefined){
                                    data.map(function(d, i){
                                    d.disabled = opts.disabled[i]
                                    })
                                    }

                                    nv.addGraph(function() {
                                    var chart = nv.models[opts.type]()
                                    .width(opts.width)
                                    .height(opts.height)

                                    if (opts.type != "bulletChart"){
                                    chart
                                    .x(function(d) { return d[opts.x] })
                                    .y(function(d) { return d[opts.y] })
                                    }


{{{ chart }}}

{{{ xAxis }}}
{{{ x2Axis }}}

{{{ yAxis }}}

                                    d3.select("#" + opts.id)
                                    .append("svg")
                                    .datum(data)
                                    .transition().duration(500)
                                    .call(chart);
                                    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
                                    return chart;
                                    },%s);
                                    };
                                    </script>','function() {
                                    var svg = d3.select("svg");

                                    var donut = svg.selectAll("g.nv-slice");
                                    console.log(donut)
                                    // Insert first line of text into middle of donut pie chart
                                    donut.insert("text", "g")
                                    .text("Line One")
                                    .attr("class", "middle")
                                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                                    .style("fill", "#000");
                                    // Insert second line of text into middle of donut pie chart
                                    donut.insert("text", "g")
                                    .text("Line Two")
                                    .attr("class", "middle")
                                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                    .attr("dy", ".85em")
                                    .style("fill", "#000");}'))
p5
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs1", "Slide", min = 5, max = 10, value = 7)
  ),
  mainPanel(
  showOutput("plot", "nvd3"))
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I want to print input$obs1in the middle of the circle, how would I change the code. Really appreciate your help.